# Erro ao tentar consultar tabela com sequelize em produção - "code: 42P01"

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, postgresql, express.js, sequelize-js

Sou novo em dev e desculpem se eu não souber explicar logo de primeira, mas estou fazendo uma aplicação com Nodejs, Express e Postgres.
Localmente estou trabalhando com docker pra criar meu banco de dados postgres. Todas as minhas tabelas com relacionamento estão funcionando legal.

Quando subo a aplicação via `git push heroku master` o build da sucesso e as as migrations são criadas normalmente, logo não parece ser erro de conexão.

Por exemplo, quando faço um registro no BD local, recebo isso:

```
{
  "id": "c467d8e3-116f-4acf-b890-04486df9ec3f",
  "name": "FCosta",
  "email": "fcosta@gmail.com"
}
```

Quando subo pro heroku e tento fazer o registro, recebo isso:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
      "length": 105,
      "name": "error",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "code": "42P01",
      "position": "184",
      "file": "parse_relation.c",
      "line": "1373",
      "routine": "parserOpenTable",
      "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"name\", \"last_name\", \"email\", \"password_hash\", \"interests\", \"cpf\", \"fone\", \"address\", \"city\", \"state\", \"profession\", \"skills\", \"avatar_id\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\" WHERE \"User\".\"email\" = 'flp@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;"
    },
    "original": {
      "length": 105,
      "name": "error",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "code": "42P01",
      "position": "184",
      "file": "parse_relation.c",
      "line": "1373",
      "routine": "parserOpenTable",
      "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"name\", \"last_name\", \"email\", \"password_hash\", \"interests\", \"cpf\", \"fone\", \"address\", \"city\", \"state\", \"profession\", \"skills\", \"avatar_id\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\" WHERE \"User\".\"email\" = 'flp@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;"
    },
}
```

**Meu package.json**

```
{
    "name": "myapp-backend",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "main": "src/server.js",
      "license": "MIT",
      "engines": {
        "node": "16.13.0",
        "npm": "8.1.0",
        "yarn": "1.22.10"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
        "queue": "nodemon src/queue.js",
        "dev:debug": "nodemon --inspect src/server.js",
        "build": "sucrase ./src -d ./dist --transforms imports",
        "start": "node dist/server.js",
        "postgres": "docker run --name myapp -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myapp -p 5432:5432 -d postgres",
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@sentry/node": "6.15.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "bee-queue": "^0.3.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
        "express-handlebars": "^6.0.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.0.13",
        "multer": "^1.4.3",
        "nodemailer": "^6.7.1",
        "nodemailer-express-handlebars": "^4.0.0",
        "pg": "^8.7.1",
        "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
        "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
        "sequelize": "^6.9.0",
        "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "youch": "^2.2.2",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
        "eslint": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0",
        "sucrase": "^3.20.3"
      }
    }
```

Meu Model de User

```
class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        last_name: Sequelize.STRING,
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        password: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
        confirm_password: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
        password_hash: Sequelize.STRING,
        interests: Sequelize.STRING,
        cpf: Sequelize.STRING,
        fone: Sequelize.STRING,
        address: Sequelize.STRING,
        city: Sequelize.STRING,
        state: Sequelize.STRING,
        profession: Sequelize.STRING,
        skills: Sequelize.STRING,
        avatar_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );

    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (user) => {
      user.id = uuidv4();
      if (user.password) {
        user.password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
      }
    });

    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Avatar, { foreignKey: 'avatar_id', as: 'avatar' });
  }

  checkPassword(password) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash);
  }
}
export default User;
```

Minha migration de User

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      password_hash: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      interests: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      cpf: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      fone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      city: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      state: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      profession: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      skills: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    }),

  down: (queryInterface) => queryInterface.dropTable('users'),
}
```

Se precisar de mais informações eu postarei aqui, mas achei estranho funcionar em dev e em prod não.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Era uma configuração que estava diferente entre dev e prod.
Estava faltando as opções de definição.

```
development: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST_DEV,
    username: process.env.DB_USER_DEV,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS_DEV,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME_DEV,
    define: {
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true,
      underscoredAll: true,
    },
  },



production: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    define: {
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true,
      underscoredAll: true,
    },
    ssl: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: { require: true, rejectUnauthorized: false },
    },
  },
```